# Annotating below axis when graph coord_flip confusion

Tags: r, ggplot2, annotations, data-visualization, data-annotations

I'm looking to build a graphic which will end up looking like this:

[image]

However at the moment I can get the annotations to sit below the axis, because I'm using `coord_flip` which is confusing the annotation positioning.

At the moment I'm getting something like this: 
[image]

Every time I change the location to go below the axis (e.g. x=-1) I lose the annotation. I've tried turning clipping off, but still no hope.

Prementive thank you!

Here is my code:

```
library(grid)
library(ggplot2)
text_poor <- textGrob("Poor", gp=gpar(fontsize=13, fontface="bold"))
text_fair <- textGrob("Fair", gp=gpar(fontsize=13, fontface="bold"))
text_good <- textGrob("Good", gp=gpar(fontsize=13, fontface="bold"))
text_excel <- textGrob("Excellent", gp=gpar(fontsize=13, fontface="bold"))

g<-ggplot(Fig1,aes(reorder(`Company ID`,Score),Score,fill=Colour))+geom_bar(stat = "identity",alpha=0.8,width=0.8,colour="black")
g1<-g +  geom_text(data=Fig1,aes(label=paste(Score,"%")),fill="white",hjust = -0.25)+
  theme(aspect.ratio = 0.75,
        legend.position = "none",
        plot.margin = unit(c(0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1), "mm"),
        axis.title  = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major.x =element_line(size = 0.3,colour="grey",linetype=2),
        panel.grid.minor =element_line(size = 0.15,colour="grey",linetype=3),
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent",colour = NA),
        axis.line= element_line(size = 0.0, colour = 1),axis.line.y=element_line(size = 0.3, colour = 1),
        axis.text.y = element_text(colour="black", size=rel(1.4),vjust=0.5),
        axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks=element_blank())+
  coord_flip()+scale_fill_manual(values=reportcol)+scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0),limits= c(0,100))+
  annotation_custom(text_poor,xmin=1,xmax=1,ymin=12.5,ymax=12.5)+
  annotation_custom(text_fair,xmin=1,xmax=1,ymin=37.5,ymax=37.5)+
  annotation_custom(text_good,xmin=1,xmax=1,ymin=62.5,ymax=62.5)+
  annotation_custom(text_excel,xmin=1,xmax=1,ymin=87.5,ymax=87.5)

gt <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(g1))
gt$layout$clip[gt$layout$name == "panel"] <- "off"
grid.draw(gt)
```

My data :

```
# A tibble: 4 × 3
  Score Colour `Company ID`
  <int>  <chr>        <chr>
1    34  Black    Company A
2    56  Black    Company B
3    39  Black    Company C
4    43    Red      Average
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Second answer using `grid` graphics.

Data used for example:

```
Fig1 <- data.frame(Score = c(34,56,39,43), Colour = c("Black", "Black", "Black", "Red"), 'Company ID' = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), check.names = FALSE)
reportcol <- c("red", "blue", "yellow", "green")
```

Packages:

```
library(grid)
library(ggplot2)
library(gtable)
```

I have only made two changes to your `ggplot` code:

1. Increased bottom plot margin
2. Removed custom annotations

I'll add these with `grid` graphics

```
g<-ggplot(Fig1,aes(reorder(`Company ID`,Score),Score,fill=Colour))+geom_bar(stat = "identity",alpha=0.8,width=0.8,colour="black")
    g1<-g +  geom_text(data=Fig1,aes(label=paste(Score,"%")),fill="white",hjust = -0.25)+
        theme(aspect.ratio = 0.75,
              legend.position = "none",
              plot.margin = unit(c(0.1, 0.1, 10, 0.1), "mm"), #Bottom Margin increased from 0.1 to 10
              axis.title  = element_blank(),
              panel.grid.major.x =element_line(size = 0.3,colour="grey",linetype=2),
              panel.grid.minor =element_line(size = 0.15,colour="grey",linetype=3),
              panel.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent",colour = NA),
              axis.line= element_line(size = 0.0, colour = 1),axis.line.y=element_line(size = 0.3, colour = 1),
              axis.text.y = element_text(colour="black", size=rel(1.4),vjust=0.5),
              axis.text.x = element_blank(),
              axis.ticks=element_blank())+
        coord_flip()+scale_fill_manual(values=reportcol)+scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0),limits= c(0,100))
```

Create `gtable` from `ggplot` object

```
g1Grob <- ggplotGrob(g1)
gtable_show_layout(g1Grob)
```

[image]

From layout, you can see the place for the labels is (10,4).

Create a 1x4 `gtable` and add textGrobs to each cell
Then add to existing gtable from original ggplot

```
labels <- c("Poor","Fair","Good","Excellent")
labelsGrob <- gtable(unit(c(1,1,1,1), c("null")),unit(1, "null"))
gtable_show_layout(labelsGrob)
```

[image]

```
for (i in 1:4) {
    text <- textGrob(labels[i], gp=gpar(fontsize=13, fontface="bold"))
    labelsGrob <- gtable_add_grob(labelsGrob, text, 1, i)    
}

g1Grob <- gtable_add_grob(g1Grob, labelsGrob, 10, 4)
```

Finally plot `gtable` object

```
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(g1Grob)
```

[image]

Comment: This is brilliant! Thanks for your help.

Comment: You're welcome. I enjoyed learning a bit more about grid graphics.

Answer (score 1):

Adjusting the x scale gives space for your labels. The annotations aren't below the axis though.

```
scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0, 0.9))
```

Full plot code

```
g<-ggplot(Fig1,aes(reorder(`Company ID`,Score),Score,fill=Colour))+geom_bar(stat = "identity",alpha=0.8,width=0.8,colour="black")
g1<-g +  geom_text(data=Fig1,aes(label=paste(Score,"%")),fill="white",hjust = -0.25)+
    theme(aspect.ratio = 0.75,
          legend.position = "none",
          plot.margin = unit(c(0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1), "mm"),
          axis.title  = element_blank(),
          panel.grid.major.x =element_line(size = 0.3,colour="grey",linetype=2),
          panel.grid.minor =element_line(size = 0.15,colour="grey",linetype=3),
          panel.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent",colour = NA),
          axis.line= element_line(size = 0.0, colour = 1),axis.line.y=element_line(size = 0.3, colour = 1),
          axis.text.y = element_text(colour="black", size=rel(1.4),vjust=0.5),
          axis.text.x = element_blank(),
          axis.ticks=element_blank())+
    coord_flip()+scale_fill_manual(values=reportcol)+scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0),limits= c(0,100))+
    scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0, 0.9)) +
    annotation_custom(text_poor,xmin=0.3,xmax=0.3,ymin=12.5,ymax=12.5)+
    annotation_custom(text_fair,xmin=0.3,xmax=0.3,ymin=37.5,ymax=37.5)+
    annotation_custom(text_good,xmin=0.3,xmax=0.3,ymin=62.5,ymax=62.5)+
    annotation_custom(text_excel,xmin=0.3,xmax=0.3,ymin=87.5,ymax=87.5)

g1
```

[image: Custom Labels]

Comment: Cheers Jeremy, this is a nice work around. Still trying to find a way of putting the annotation below the axis, just as I prefer the aesthetics.

Comment: You might need to use grid graphics for that.

Comment: I had a quick attempt, but I'm not familiar enough with the grid graphics system yet.